# UserListener::preUpdate() must be an instance of LifecycleEventArgs

Tags: php, doctrine, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.3

When you enter the login method, then, is the direction of the route login_check, I get the following error.

> ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserListener::preUpdate() must be an instance
>   of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs, instance of
>   Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs given, called in
>   /var/www/solicitud_cupos/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/ContainerAwareEventManager.php
>   on line 63 and defined in
>   /var/www/solicitud_cupos/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Doctrine/UserListener.php
>   line 76

Version: Symfony 2.3.37

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Today I had the same problem.
[FosUserBundle github](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/commit/b7e4a67a873d4e1594f0bdaca34d969efedb2903)

FosUserBundle was modified recently.
Maybe your composer version of Doctrine/orm & doctrine/doctrine-bundle not up to date.

I've now in my composer.json :

> "doctrine/orm": "~2.4,>=2.4.5"
>
> "doctrine/doctrine-bundle" : "1.5.*"
>
> "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle" : "~2.0@dev"